# Optimize query in Sql Server with a huge table

Tags: sql-server

This is my first question, so I apologize in advance if there's anything out of order. I've searched for an answer but I couldn't find anything that fit my current situation. I have this SP showed below, but the problem lies with the table "tmpBusca", which can a huge amout of data (on this case, it's about 20 million records). I've thought about using a temporary table to optimize it, but as you can see, there's not really an efficient filter, as it can be by the id or none at all.
Thanks in advance.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_filtraEstoque]  
(  
 @Fornecedor int =null,  
 @Linha int = null,  
 @CodEstoquePrincipal int  = null,  
 @CodProduto int  = null,  
 @Nomeproduto varchar(200) =  null,  
 @qtdeEstoque bit = null,  
 @medida varchar(200) =null  
)  
AS  
 BEGIN  

        SELECT  EstoqueProdutoConf.Produto AS Codigo, 
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Codigo AS Codigo2,
            EstoqueProdutoConf.PrecoConf, 
            Produto.Nome AS ProdutoNome, 
            Produto.PrecoCusto,
            Produto.PrecoVenda,
            Produto.Disponibilidade, 
            Produto.Estoque,
            Fornecedor.Nome AS Fornecedor,
            Linha.Nome AS Linha,   
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Acabamento,
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Tecido, 
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Cor,
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Configuracao4, 
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Almoxarifado,   
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Quantidade,
            Produto.Medida, 
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Disponibilidade AS Expr1,
            EstoqueProdutoConf.PrevEntrega, 
            EstoqueProdutoConf.Oc,   
            EstoqueProdutoConf.QuantidadeDemonstracao, 
            EstoqueProdutoConf.CodEstoquePrincipal  
    FROM EstoqueProdutoConf
         INNER JOIN Produto ON EstoqueProdutoConf.Produto = Produto.Codigo
         INNER JOIN Fornecedor ON Produto.Fornecedor = Fornecedor.Codigo
         INNER JOIN Linha ON Produto.Linha = Linha.Codigo
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tmpBusca ON EstoqueProdutoConf.Produto = tmpBusca.Produto
                                 AND EstoqueProdutoConf.Acabamento = tmpBusca.Configuracao1
                                 AND EstoqueProdutoConf.Tecido = tmpBusca.Configuracao2
                                 AND EstoqueProdutoConf.Cor = tmpBusca.Configuracao3
                                 AND EstoqueProdutoConf.Configuracao4 = tmpBusca.Configuracao4  
    WHERE (Fornecedor.Codigo = @Fornecedor OR @Fornecedor is null)   
      AND (Produto.Linha = @Linha OR @Linha is null)  
      AND (EstoqueProdutoConf.CodEstoquePrincipal = @CodEstoquePrincipal OR @CodEstoquePrincipal is null)   
      AND (CONVERT(varchar(20), tmpBusca.id) = @CodProduto OR @CodProduto is null)   
      AND (Produto.Nome LIKE '%' + @Nomeproduto + '%' OR @Nomeproduto is null)   
      AND (@qtdeEstoque is null OR EstoqueProdutoConf.Quantidade<>0)  
      AND (@medida is null OR produto.Medida  like '%' + @medida + '%' )  
    ORDER BY Fornecedor.nome  

END
```

Comment: index the table

Comment: In addition to indexing, read http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.

Comment: As it's either just one record or all of it, I don't think indexing would be really useful in this case.

Comment: There looks to be a couple of problems here. Firstly, This looks to be like a "catch-all query"; as in, if you supply *`NULL`* across the board, everything is returned. These, more than often, perform poorly. Next, you have wildcard searching at the start of a string. Despite what @WhatsThePoint commented, Indexing won't help you there; you can't use an index in a statement like `WHERE A.Column LIKE '%A%'`. Also, you have conversions in there as well. Again, you can't use indexes in `WHERE` or `ON` with `CONVERT`. I think, honestly, the query is just fundamentally slow, and needs a rethink.

Comment: Thanks Dan Guzman. I'll read it.

Comment: Like expressions will slow down your performance and conversion in your where clause will cost you

Comment: @Larnu I didn't read the question fully, I saw the title, read the body commented and left. I didn't look at the code, otherwise I probably would've spotted that

Comment: Thanks, Larnu. Yeah, it's a really poor query. I'm rethinking it, but I don't really have a good idea so far. I'll just keep doing the trial and error method, I think.

Comment: Not a performance thing but if you used some aliases here you could reduce the wall of text query and make it look a lot nicer. You might also take a peek at this. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix And here is another great read about catch-all type queries. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: One method to handle these types of "catch all" queries is to use `IF` logic, and have different queries based on what parameters don't have a *`NULL`* provided. These *can*, however, perform just as badly. In truth, however, I'm not sure this is really going to help, as you still need to try and cater for the wildcards and `CONVERT`. The `CONVERT` needs to go, so you can use something SARGable, however, with the wildcards you're a bit stuck as is. You might need to consider implementing FULLTEXT indexing.

Comment: I think I've found the solution, guys. For anyone that might find it useful: in this case, I don't really use the data from the tmpBusca table, it's in the query just in case the user tries to do an id search. But, as in most cases, he won't, I'll remove it from this query and check before if it has the id or not. In case it does, then it's a different query.